# Scaleable UIBezier in Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift2, core-graphics, uibezierpath, swift3

I'm trying to design a scaleable `UIBezier`.

This is my Swift Code:

```
@IBDesignable
class AnimatedRingView: UIView {


     override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        //// Color Declarations
        let strokeColor = UIColor(red: 1.000, green: 0.706, blue: 0.004, alpha: 1.000)

        //// bezier Drawing
        let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 48.93, y: 266.07))
        bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 48.93, y: 53.93), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: -9.64, y: 207.49), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: -9.64, y: 112.51))
        bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 261.07, y: 53.93), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 107.51, y: -4.64), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 202.49, y: -4.64))
        bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 261.07, y: 266.07), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 319.64, y: 112.51), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 319.64, y: 207.49))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 261.07, y: 266.07))
        bezierPath.lineCapStyle = .round;

        bezierPath.lineJoinStyle = .round;

        strokeColor.setStroke()
        bezierPath.lineWidth = 10
        bezierPath.stroke()

     }

}
```

This is the result:

[image]

---

My problem:
To save time, I created the `UIBezierPath` by PaintCode:

[image]

And as you can see above, we have a **width and height** for the `UIBezierPath`, however, the code is displayed points of `UIBezierPath` ...

**How can I create a size variable to assign a value via code (or inspector) that automatically identify the points of `UIBezierPath`?**

Is this possible? Need help!

Comment: you can create a size variable and connect it to width and height.

Comment: You have an example?

Comment: I mean , in the paint code tool , on the left hand side you can see the variable panel. You can add a size variable, and drag that variable to the x and y field or w,h field on right side.

Comment: It's not possible: http://imgur.com/a/sVvik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you creating a Circular Arc, using Bezier Curves for that purpose seems like overkill.

With UIBezierPath, you can use this function:

func addArcWithCenter(_ center: CGPoint,
               radius radius: CGFloat,
           startAngle startAngle: CGFloat,
             endAngle endAngle: CGFloat,
            clockwise clockwise: Bool)

and set a radius, along with the requisite start and end angles.

If you really must use cubic Béziers for the purpose, you should use the magic number kappa which equals 0.5522847498, and that is the control points for a circle built out of cubic Béziers.

I have placed a small demo of what I'm describing on my web site at:

http://www.trilithon.com/download/AnimatedRingView.zip

Hope That Helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! Just what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

*Bezier* objects do not support attaching variables to their dimensions, but you can use *Oval* object with custom start/end angles.

[image: Attaching variable to Oval]

<sub>— PaintCode Support</sub>